# SQLSTATE[HY000] When trying to select and pass a value from a dropdown

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I am trying to add a select box in my application in order for a user to choose a Category to assign to his Post.

The Categories and Post tables in my database are separate and there is a column category_id in Posts which is a foreign key to the Categories table.

My create blade for the posts is:

```
<div class="container">
    <form method="POST" action="/posts">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        <div>
            <label>Title</label>
            <input type="text" name="title" required>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Slug</label>
            <input type="text" name="slug" required>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Subtitle</label>
            <input type="text" name="subtitle" required>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Content</label>
            <input type="text" name="content" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control" name="categories_id">
                @foreach($categories as $category)
                    <option value="{{$category->title}}">{{$category->title}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
        <div  style="margin-top: 10px">
            <input type="submit" value="Make Post">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

the store function on my Posts Controller is:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $post = new Post();

    $post->title = request('title');
    $post->slug = request('slug');
    $post->subtitle = request('subtitle');
    $post->content = request('content');
    $post->save();

    return redirect('/posts');
}
```

and create function is

```
public function create()
{
    $categories = Category::all(['id','title']);
    return view('posts.create',compact('categories',$categories));
}
```

and finally my model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    public $table = "posts";
}
```

Currently when i try to choose an option i get an

> SQLSTATE[HY000]:  General error: 1364 Field 'category_id' doesn't have a default value.

I dont want it to be null. and every post should be associated with 1 category at least

Comment: I think you are not 'saving' the categories_id value when you save your post ($post->save()). Shouldn't it be $post->categories_id = $request->input('categories_id') ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `select`, use the category's ID instead of the title as the value.

```
<select class="form-control" name="category_id">
    @foreach($categories as $category)
        <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->title }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Then, in your `store()` method, pass that value into the posts `create()` method (or you can use `$post = new Post()` and assign them manually, it'll work too, but this is a tad shorter).

This assumes that the user selected a category - you don't appear to have any validation, so you could perhaps look into using a validator (see https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation).

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $post = Post::create($request->only("title", "slug", "subtitle", "content", "category_id"));

    return redirect('/posts');
}
```

When using the `create()` or `update()` methods, you need to specify which fields are mass-assignable. You can do this by adding them to the `$fillable` property of the model.

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public $table = "posts";

    protected $fillable = ["title", "slug", "subtitle", "content", "category_id"];
}
```

Comment: when i do what you say i get Add [title] to fillable property to allow mass assignment on [App\Post].

Comment: Check your `$fillable` property in the `Post` model. It should be something like `protected $fillable = ["title", "slug", "subtitle", "content", "category_id"];`

Comment: i have updated my select as you said. and done every other step. when i add the fillable i get the same error. that the field category_id doesn't have a default value

Comment: Then you didn't update the `store()` method and/or the `name` property of your `<select>`.

Comment: ITS ALIIIVE. Thank you very very much! Now i have to find a way to make it accept more than one category. but you saved my life along with @minatula . thank you again!

Comment: If you want to have more than one category, you're looking for a "*one to many*" relationship. You need a `category_post` table, with `category_id`, `post_id`. Then define a relation in your Post model of `function categories() { return $this->hasMany(Category::class); }` -- so the categories are stored in a different table, not on the `posts` table.

Comment: that means i will have to redo my migrations since there wont be a need for a foreign key from posts to categories? 

So ill have to create a table called category_post and have a foreign key from posts to the new table and a foreign key from categories to that table as well. right?

Comment: Correct, you won't have a `category_id` column in your `posts` table. You also need to modify your `store()` to insert into the relation instead of the `Post` model. Something like `$post->categories()->attach($request->category_id);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202110/discussion-between-andreas-panteli-and-qirel).

Answer (score 1):

In the `store()` method before `save()` you need to add

```
$post->content = request('categories_id');
```

to add category id in new post. And you need to make sure, that user will choose category

Comment: And @Qirel is right, you need use category's ID instead of the title as the value

Comment: i tried your way as well. when i press make post i get redirected to the index page but the post is not shown. my mistake. i forgot the save. but when i do as you say i get the default value issue